# Hub binding not working in Template10

Tags: winrt-xaml, win-universal-app, template10

I'm trying to put a hub in a page, but it seems that Binding is not functioning correct. I used the Template10 Hamburger sample and tried to put a hub in the main page. As I test I just encapsulate the existing stackpanel inside a hub section but it seems to break the binding on the button click event.

*Error when building*:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

```
<HubSection>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Orientation="Horizontal"
        Padding="12,8,0,0">

            <controls:Resizer>
                <TextBox Width="200" MinWidth="200" MinHeight="60"
             Margin="0" Header="Parameter to pass"
             Text="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             TextWrapping="Wrap">
                    <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                        <Behaviors:TextBoxEnterKeyBehavior>
                            <Core:CallMethodAction MethodName="GotoDetailsPage" TargetObject="{Binding}" />
                        </Behaviors:TextBoxEnterKeyBehavior>
                        <Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                            <Behaviors:FocusAction />
                        </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
                    </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                </TextBox>
            </controls:Resizer>
            <Button Margin="12,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
        Click="{x:Bind ViewModel.GotoDetailsPage}" Content="Submit" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</HubSection>
```

Comment: just to add that I've tried this with a Pivot and it works fine so i'm not sure how binding differ in Hub. Tried searching around but haven't found anything that works.

Comment: Maybe there should not be ViewModel in your x:Bind, because the viewModel is Page itself.

Comment: hi Alamakanambra, from what I understand with compiled binding you need to reference the class AND property unlike traditional binding.

Maybe I was not explicit in my original question but this works outside a Hub. I'm using the Template10 Hamburger project template and x:Bind works. I merely took what was working and encapsulate it in a Hub as I want this particular page to be a hub.

Also as mentioned in my subsequent comment, the code also work when used in a Pivot.

For what it's worth, I've tried all combos of x:Bind and Binding, adding DataContext at HubSection etc ... to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can certainly explain the problem to you. Because you are using the hub control and because the hub control uses hub sections and because the hub section, unlike almost any other control in your toolbox, uses data templates to draw its content, the data context of every element inside the data template is no longer the data context of the outside page. That is to say, your binding fails because you are binding to a new class that does not have the method you need.

As for a solution, you could have done this:

```
<Core:CallMethodAction MethodName="GotoDetailsPage" TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=ViewModel}" />
```

That syntax would have brought your context back to the page's view model. But your solution seems to work for you. I would stick with what works.

Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks Jerry for the advice. I kinda understands the concept from watching your mva but unfortunately still haven't got my head around it when actually doing. 

Does it mean that we cannot use compiled binding like the button click event from the code in my question?

Are you able to point me to some samples of data binding within Hub control? Preferably using compiled binding because for beginners like me it's easier to troubleshoot. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Finally managed to get the button click to work with Binding using behavior interaction. Below is the code. If anyone else got better suggestion feel free to comment.

```
    <Button Margin="12,0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Content="Submit" >
        <Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <Core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click">
                <Core:CallMethodAction MethodName="GotoDetailsPage" TargetObject="{Binding}" />
            </Core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </Interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    </Button>
```